# configure the business data connectivity service

Tags: sharepoint-server, bcs

I'm getting ready to configure the business data connectivity service on central admin

Question:

- Does it matter which existing application pool I choose to use?
- I don't have a testing environment, so is this something I should do during non business hour? ( looks like the existing application services have their own application pool)
- Does it matter if I use an existing managed account or do    I need to register a new managed account for this service?

Thanks in advance ( below is pic of our App. Pools)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please use **SharePoint Web Services System**. Its recommended to use less application pool. There is no impact on other application.

Thanks

Surya

Answer (score 1):

For your questions:

1. You can use existing application pool.
2. There is no need to configure Business Data Connectivity Service in non-business hours.
3. You can use either existing managed account or create a new managed account.